A lengthy integral $\frac{\int_{0}^{a} x^4 \sqrt{a^2 - x^2} \, dx}{\int_{0}^{a} x^2 \sqrt{a^2 - x^2} \, dx}$
$$\frac{\int_{0}^{a} x^4 \sqrt{a^2 - x^2} \ dx}{\int_{0}^{a} x^2 \sqrt{a^2 - x^2} \ dx}$$
I tried solving this using trigonometric substitution, and it transforms into a very lengthy expression. Is there any easier way to do this problem?
EDIT
After substitution the integral looks like this: $$= \frac{a^{6} \int \cos^{2}\left(u\right) \sin^{4}\left(u\right) \, du}{ a^{4} \int \cos^{2}\left(u\right) \sin^{2}\left(u\right) \, du}$$
( Substituting $x = a \sin (u)$ and $dx = a \cos (u) \, du$ in both numerator and denominator )
The denominator term looks relatively easy; however, the integral in the numerator is quiet lengthy.

Do you want a solution for solving the integral in the numerator or just another method?

@rohit1729 The most efficient solution would be to use the beta function and avoid needing the antiderivatives altogether.

If you define $I(n)=\int^{a}_{0} x^{2n}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\ dx$, then Integration by parts gives $I(n)$ in terms of $I(n-1)$ and $I(0)$ is a quarter of the area of a circle. Not much quicker but another way.

After your trigonometric substitution, use the change of variables : $\int_a^b f(x)dx = \int_a^b f(a+b-x)dx$

Let
$$ K=\int_0^{\frac\pi2} \cos^{2}\left(u\right) \sin^{2}\left(u\right)\,du. $$
Noting
\begin{align} L&:=\int_0^{\frac\pi2} \cos^{2}\left(u\right) \sin^{4}\left(u\right) \, du=\int_0^{\frac\pi2} \cos^{2}\left(u\right) \sin^{2}\left(u\right)(1-\cos^2(u)) \, du \\ &=K-\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\cos^4(u)\sin^2(u) \, du=K-L \end{align}
one has
$$ L=\frac12K $$
and hence
$$\frac{\int_{0}^{a} x^4 \sqrt{a^2 - x^2} \ dx}{\int_{0}^{a} x^2 \sqrt{a^2 - x^2} \ dx}=\frac{a^2}{2}.$$

Alternatively, integrate by parts as follows
\begin{align}\int_{0}^{a} x^4 \sqrt{a^2 - x^2} \ dx
=&\int_{0}^{a} \frac{x^3}{(a^2-x^2)^{3/2}}\ d\bigg[ -\frac16(a^2-x^3)^3\bigg]\\
\overset{ibp}=& \ \frac{a^2}2 \int_{0}^{a} x^2 \sqrt{a^2 - x^2} \ dx
\end{align}

In the numerator, introducing the limit, we get:
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^2u\sin^4u du=B\left(\frac52,\frac32\right)=\frac 12 \frac{\Gamma(\frac52)\Gamma(\frac32)}{\Gamma(4)}
$$
where $\Gamma$ is the gamma function, in case you do not know. It has a value of:
$$
B\left(\frac52,\frac32\right)=\frac{\pi}{32}
$$
Similarly, the denominator is:
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^2u\sin^2u du=B\left(\frac32,\frac32\right)=\frac {\pi}{16}
$$
Therefore, the value of the total integral is: $$\frac{a^2}{2}$$

What does the $B$ represent? I am familiar with the gamma function but have never seen the $B$.

That's the beta function. Their exists a relationship: $$B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$

As defined in my comment above,
$I(n) = \int^a_0 x^{2n-1}\ x\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\ dx$ which by parts is
$[-\frac{1}{3}x^{2n-1}(a^2-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}]^a_0+\frac{1}{3}\int^a_0 (2n-1)x^{2n-2}(a^2-x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}\ dx $
which is $\frac{1}{3}(2n-1)(a^2 I(n-1)-I(n))$
Thus $I(n)=\dfrac{2n-1}{2n+2}a^2 I(n-1).$
Thus you want $\dfrac{I(2)}{I(1)}=\dfrac{3a^2}{6}=\dfrac{a^2}{2}$.

Nice use of the reduction method :-)

The Wallis integrals $$W_n:=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^nu\,du$$ are known to satisfy
$$nW_n=(n-1)W_{n-2}.$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{align}\frac{\int_0^ax^n\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\,dx}{\int_0^ax^{n-2}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\,dx}&=\frac{a^{n+2}\int\cos^2u\sin^nu\,du}{a^n\int\cos^2u\sin^{n-2}u\,du}\\&=a^2\frac{W_n-W_{n+2}}{W_{n-2}-W_n}\\&=a^2\frac{W_n-\frac{n+1}{n+2}W_n}{\frac n{n-1}W_n-W_n}\\&=a^2\frac{n-1}{n+2}.\end{align}$$
